# Making a function call in React affect only the item clicked on

Tags: reactjs

I have a few buttons acting as toggles. I have a function that creates the toggle color changes on the UI. (more functionality will follow eventually) for now, I just need the color change to happen only to the button that is being clicked on instead of all buttons where the function is used. There has to be a better way to do this than making a function for each button.

*Right now, although the function works, it changes the color on all buttons regardless of which one I click on. I'm trying to make the function fire only on the button being clicked on.

Example

state in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { 
       colorActive: "true", 
   };
   this.toggleDayButton = this.toggleDayButton.bind(this);
}
```

Function

```
toggleDayButton = () => {
   this.setState({ colorActive: !this.state.colorActive });
};
```

Buttons

```
<Button 
    onClick={(e) => this.toggleDayButton(e)} 
    color={this.state.colorActive ? "primary" : "default"}>
    Sunday
</Button>  
<Button
    onClick={(e) => this.toggleDayButton(e)}
    color={this.state.colorActive ? "primary" : "default"}>
    Monday
</Button>  
...
... 
<Button
    onClick={(e) => this.toggleDayButton(e)}
    color={this.state.colorActive ? "primary" : "default"}>
    Saturday
</Button>
```

I know this extremely simple (judging by how easy this would be in jQuery) and React is supposed to be a million times more flexible. Help me out here guys. (New to react as you can tell)

Thanks in advance

Comment: post entire code of Button component and Buttons Component. Seems like this.toggleDayButton is the same irrespective of the button clicked. You may need to pass an Id to toggleDayButton to identify which Button's state to be modified.

Comment: Yea - I'm basically implementing the idea ssk mentions. I saw this comment only after I posted.